# MQTT auth and password not working in python file

Tags: python, passwords, mqtt, mosquitto

The user and password are working fine when using the mosquitto pub/sub in the command line but when I try to run the .py file I get the "Received CONNACK (0, 5)" "bad connection Returned".What am I missing?

```
#! c:\python34\python.exe
#!/usr/bin/env python


import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  
import time

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
        print("log: "+buf)
        client.tls_set()
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
        print("DisConnected result code "+str(rc))

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
        topic=msg.topic
        m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
        print("message received",m_decode)
broker="test.mosquitto.org"
client = mqtt.Client("python1")
user="teste"
password="teste"

client.username_pw_set(user,password=password)
client.on_connect=on_connect  
client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
client.on_log=on_log
client.on_message=on_message
print("Connecting to broker ",broker)

client.connect(broker,1884)      
client.loop_start()  
client.subscribe("house/sensor1")
client.publish("house/sensor1","my first message")
time.sleep(4)
client.loop_stop()    
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: You need to use the username/passwords listed at the bottom of the http://test.mosquitto.org page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

You must use the username/password pairs mentioned on http://test.mosquitto.org when using the test.mosquitto.org broker.

> The authenticated listeners require a username / password:
>
> ```
> rw / readwrite : read/write access to the # topic hierarchy
> ro / readonly : read only access to the # topic hierarchy
> wo / writeonly : write only access to the # topic hierarch
> ```